# Bipartite graph minimal amount of vertices required

Tags: graphs, bipartite-matching, vertex-cover, bipartite-graph

I have a bipartite graph made of two sets (`SET 1` and `SET 2`) and I want to determine how many vertices from the `SET 1` I can remove while still having 
every vertex of the `SET 2` connected to at least one vertex of the `SET 1`.
[image: example graph]
In this example, `E` and `F` can obviously be removed as `D` and `C` are connected `5` and `6`.
But we could also remove `B` as `A` and `C` together cover more points. But so far I only have a very slow implementation of this which is to compare every vertex of `SET 1` to every combination of vertices of `SET1`.
Is there any smart way to do this? I've been thinking about [Kőnig's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%91nig%27s_theorem_(graph_theory)) but I didn't find a way to use it in this context as it seems to be made for undirected bipartite graphs.

Also, there are some constraints the input follows:
-Every element of `SET 2` is connected to `SET 1`
-Every node of `SET 2` is connected exactly to two vertices of `SET 1`

Comment: Does any one know if this problem has a formal name? I think I might have come across it once before but I can't recall its name.

Comment: @narek Bojikian Yeah, this looks like a very basic problem in bipartite graphs, but I couldn't find any ressources about that; https://tryalgo.org/en/matching/2016/08/05/konig/ is the closest I found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define a graph $G=(V,E)$, for which:

- Set of vertices $V$ is identical to your `SET1`.
- Two vertices $v_1,v_2 \in V$ are connected by an edge, if and only if there exists a vertex from the `SET2`, incident to both $v_1$ and $v_2$ in your bipartite graph.

For instance, the graph below corresponds to the bipartite graph from the example in your question:

[image: ABCDEF]

Now, your problem is reduced to the [Minimum Vertex Cover](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MinimumVertexCover.html) problem on the graph $G$, defined above, so you'll be able to use known algorithms to find minimum vertex cover in your `SET1` **only**.

This graph $G$ doesn't have any special structure, which could be used to find its minimum vertex cover more effectively than in general case. Also, *any* graph can be transformed to your bipartite graph form by splitting each edge by a new vertex. So, it means that your problem is equivalent to the minimum vertex cover problem, which is NP-complete - thanks to @narekBojikian for mentioning that in his answer.

Comment: But minimum vertex cover is np-hard, do you think the proposed problem is also np-hard? If not this is not very useful approach since we will be interested in a polynomial solution

Comment: @narekBojikian - I don't see any way to solve it in polynomial time.

Comment: You are right, I just proposed a reduction from vertex-cover, I hope I did not mess up any thing among my calculation since @D.W. is suggesting it is solvable through max-flow

Comment: Isn't the graph G bipartite?

Comment: Not necessarily - consider a $K_3$ (triangle)

Comment: Yes, you're right.
But actually this problem is part of a bigger one which makes this case impossible (I believe)

Answer (score 1):

This problem is NP-Hard. I will present a simple reduction from the vertex-cover problem to this problem. This reduction shows that there is probably no polynomial time algorithm for this problem, since such an algorithm will implies a polynomial time algorithm for the vertex cover problem which will implies that P=NP, since the vertex cover problem is NP-complete.

So given a graph $G(V, E)$ as an instance of the vertex cover problem, Let us build the bipartite graph $G'(V_1, V_2, E')$, where $V_1$ is a copy of $V$, $V_2$ is a copy of $E$ and $E'$ represent the incident relation in the graph, meaning that a vertex $v_1 \in V_1$ is adjacent to a vertex $v_2 \in V_2$ in $G'$, if the the edge corresponding to $v_2$ in $E$ is incident to the vertex corresponding to $v_1$ in $V$. Let $n$ be the number of vertices and $m$ the number of edges in the given graph.

Let us call your problem $P$. We claim that $G$ admits a vertex cover of size $k$, if and only if the problem $P$ on the graph $G'$ admits a solution of size $n - k$.

Proof. Note that $P$ admits a solution of size $n-k$, meaning that there are $k$ vertices adjacent to all vertices in $V_2$, meaning that there are $k$ vertices in $V$ incident to all edges in $E$, meaning that $G$ has a vertex cover of size $k$.

This proof shows the correctness of the reduction in both directions. (If $G$ admits a vertex cover of size $k$ then $G'$ admits a solution of $P$ of size $n-k$ and if $G'$ admits a solution of size $n-k$ then $G$ admits a vertex cover of size $k$).

This completes the proof that $P$ is NP-hard.
@HEKTO showed a reduction in the other direction, proving that $P$ is NP-complete as well.